# Como usar o NOT IN com os dados de outro servidor no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, query

Montei uma tabela com Dados que **não** devem ser buscados, vou chama-la aqui de *Tabela_not*. Os dados que estavam nessa tabela são esses:

```
|Tabela_Not|
  Londres
  Tóquio
  Paris
```

E apliquei essa Query para fazer as buscas descartando os itens da *Tabela_Not*:

```
SELECT * FROM BancoANoServidor1.registros WHERE Papel NOT IN (SELECT Papel FROM BancoANoServidor1.Tabela_Not);
```

Como é possível ver na Query, as duas tabelas estão no mesmo banco/servidor, a minha questão é, a tabela *registros* em que eu gostaria de fazer está busca está em outro Servidor (*BancoBNoServidor2.registros*).

Tem como resolver isso usando apenas Mysql? Ou tem outra forma de resolver isso no PHP? Existe como fazer algo tipo:

```
$Query_not = "SELECT Papel FROM BancoANoServidor1.Tabela_Not";
$result_not = mysqli_query($conecta1, $Query_not);

$Query_return = "SELECT * FROM BancoBNoServidor2.registros WHERE Papel NOT IN ($result_not)";
$return = mysqli_query($conecta2, $Query_return);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer um loop na primeira query.

A lógica seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
while $result_not 
$negar = $negar + $result_not["Papel"] + ","
```

No final do loop você vai ter na variável $negar algo como: "Londres, Tóquio, Paris"

Ai sim você pode usar:

```
$Query_return = "SELECT * FROM BancoBNoServidor2.registros WHERE Papel NOT IN ($negar)";
```

Comment: Vai dar erro pq vai ficar com uma virgula no final não?

Comment: @Shinchila_Matadora esse código não funciona, mas pode se reciclar a lógica.

Comment: $negar = substr($negar , 0, strlen(negar)-1);

Comment: @ClaudioScarpaFilho, vou tentar implementar aqui, muito obrigado